# How to address a list into a list?

Tags: python, list

How to address a list into a list? #python

I have a list

```
 players_card = []
```

Then I have a list of this list

```
player = [players_card for i in range(num_players)]
```

I want to give one card to all players in my list of lists, so I have tried with this.

```
for i in range(0,num_players):
    player[i].append(deck.pop(0))
```

I'm supposing this loop is giving a card to each of my players (It's not `player[i]` a list containing the cards of each player??)

If I print the results while in the loop I'm getting this kind of output:

```
print( str(i) + " " + str(player[i]) )
0 [6]
1 [6, 10]
2 [6, 10, 10]
3 [6, 10, 10, 2]
```

Where am i wrong?

When doing the first tests with `player[0]` it seemed to work.

Comment: You are giving each player the very same `player_cards` list - it doesn't matter which player number you're using to index into `player`, you're always referencing the same list.  You need to give everybody their own, individual list - `player = [[] for i in range(num_players)]` perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your players are sharing the same hand because you assign the same list to each.

```
player = [player_cards for i in range(num_players)]
```

I think you meant to create a new hand for each player.  Also, I prefer to name lists in the plural:

```
players = [[] for i in range(num_players)]
```

Furthermore, I'd suggest a more "Pythonic" loop syntax when dealing. See how naming the list in the plural makes this read more clearly?

```
for player in players:
        player.append(deck.pop(0))
```